# need help to generate SQL query

Tags: sql

there are two tables Employee and Department

**Employee table**

```
 EmpID  EmpName
 E001   Jack
 E002   Jill
```

**Department table**

```
DeptID  DeptName
D001    IT
D002    HR
```

**Result**

```
ID     Name      Type
E001    Jack    Employee
E002    Jill    Employee
D001    IT      Department
D002    HR      Department
```

how to add that third column?

Comment: Do a UNION ALL. Select string literals for the 3rd col.

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use fix values:

```
select EMPID, EMPNAME, 'Employee' as TYPE from Employee 
Union all
select DeptID  , DeptName, 'Department'  as TYPE from Department
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `union all` ?

```
select EmpID as ID, EmpName as Name, 'Employee' as Type
from Employee e union all
select DeptID , DeptName, 'Department'
from Department d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmpID AS ID, EmpName AS Name, 'Employee' AS [Type]
FROM Employees
UNION ALL
SELECT DeptID AS ID, DeptName AS Name, 'Department' AS [Type]
From Departments
```

I would suggest replacing the column name "Type" with a non-reserved word.